# git line range log -- for what commit line numbers refer

Tags: git, git-log

I have some file foo.hpp and a line there that was added on commit A at line number 4332. Now (at HEAD) this line is at position 4776

Neither

```
1) git log -L 4330,4335:foo.hpp
```

nor

```
2) git log -L 4774,4778:foo.hpp
```

doesn't give me commit A with the line added.

Writing

```
3) git log <commit A hash> -L 4330,4335:foo.hpp
```

gives me commit A and some older commits. So I assume that, when revision is entered, understand line range as a range of lines at specific revision. But than I don't get why the 2nd variant didn't show me this line change, since specifying no revision essentially makes it being set to HEAD.

Can anyone explain me such a behaviour? If I specify the line range, than how git understands it (I mean, which commit does this line range correspond for?)

In case if git understands line range as a line range for each commit, than why the 1st variant didn't help me? And is there any tool to track line range intellectually (so that git automatically updates it accordingly to file changes)?

Comment: It should indeed be tracking the line based on HEAD so your second solution should work. Just to make sure: you don't have uncommitted changes on that file, right?

Comment: @JulienLopez, yes, there no changes compared to HEAD. If there were, however, does it matter? I believed that log works on commits => index, not depending on current working tree state.

Comment: Yes, so if you had uncommitted changes, the lines would possibly have been different between your changes and HEAD. Well, I don't think I can help you then, I haven't used `git log -L` much. Sorry.